# How can I solve 403:Forbidden whilst using a docker container?

Tags: docker, portforwarding, docker-for-windows

I'm new to Docker and currently following this tutorial:

> [Learn Docker in 12 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFl2mCHdv24)

I created the necessary files and I made it up to display "Hello World!" on localhost:80.

Beyond that point, I tried to mount the container using the direct reference to my folder so I can update the index.php file to mimic the development evironment, and then I come with this error:

[image: Forbidden]

All I did is change the way the image is ran so I can update the content of the index.php file and see the changes reflect in the webpage when I hit F5.

*Currently using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 Pro*

*Docker for Windows is running*

I followed every steps scrupulously so I don't get myself fooled and it didn't work for me it seems.

To answer Mornor's question, here is the result for **`docker ps`**

[image: docker ps]

And here for **`docker logs [container-name]`**

[image: docker logs ae]

And since I now better understand what happens under the hood, how do I go to solve my problem illustrated in the log?

Here is my **`Dockfile`**

[image: Dockerfile]

And the command I executed to run my image:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /wmi/tutorials/docker/src/:/var/www/html/ hello-world
```

And so you see that the file exists:

[image: path to index.php]

Comment: Could you issue a `docker ps` and a `docker logs [container_name]` to check if something's wrong here may be?

Comment: Have you exposed port 80 in dockerfile?

Comment: @mulg0r Yes I did and I put a screenshot of my Dockerfile in the edit I just made.

Comment: @Mornor Just edited so one can see the result from the logs. It's definitely the mapping and I don't know how to solve this. :(

Comment: Could it be as simple as you are missing the drive letter c: from your mapping?

docker run -p 80:80 -v c:/wmi/tutorials/docker/src/:/var/www/html/ hello-world

Comment: @AnttiA Docker for Windows prompts me to share the file path and I share it. But then, nothing else happens and the container doesn't seem to run.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone, using Docker for Windows, one needs to share the drive from which the source is to be bound to the container's folder so it can access it. Beware though, if you're using AzureAD like I do, it just won't work per issue #649: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/649. In order to share the drive, one needs to create a local to the machine admin account and share the drive with this local admin account in order for the share to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're wrongly mouting your `index.php`. What you could do to debug it, is to firstly check if the `index.php` is indeed mounted within the container. 
 
You could issue the following command :

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /wmi/tutorials/docker/src/:/var/www/html/ hello-world bash -c 'ls -lsh /var/www/html/'
```

(use `sh` instead of `bash` if it does not work). If you can indeed see a `index.php`, then congratulations your file is correctly mounted, and the error is not coming from Docker, but from Apache.

If `index.php` is not there, then you have to check your Dockerfile. You mount `src/`, check if `/src` is in the same directory as your Dockerfile.

Keep us updated :)

Comment: @AnttiA had part of the answer. Whilst putting `C:` in front of my host path to share, Docker for Windows prompted me whether I wanted to share my drive with my containers. When I said yes, it required my credentials which I provided. And then, because I'm using AzureAD, Docker just kept doing nothing and left the drive unshared, which caused the mount to fail. After further research, it is a flaw in Docker that is known by the Docker community and has been reported on GitHub. The workaround is to create a local account and make this an admin of local computer then share drive using this user.

Comment: Accepted answer because even though Antti A's answer shows a way, this one also provides a more technical Docker related solution to find out whether the file was there or not. If I could accept both, I would. Everyone provided very coherent thoughts and in the end it lead to a Docker's issue.

Answer (score 2):

Error is coming from Apache which tries to show you the directory contents as there is no index file available. Either your docker mapping is not working correctly, or your apache does not have php support installed on it. You are accessing http://localhost, try http://localhost/index.php.

If you get same error, problem is with mapping. If you get php code the problem is with missing PHP support in Apache.

Comment: I just tried and I hit a 404:File not found. The `docker logs` command shows that my *index.php* file wasn't mapped or something as stated in my edit.

Comment: Please see comments on @Mornor's answer. You were right, it was about the mapping because the file, `index.php`, was not present. But, on the other hand, never was it mentioned anywhere I looked for a shared drive that was to be set in order to achieve this. Besides, Docker for Windows Shared Drive feature will not work using an AzureAD which, to my surprise, could prove to be useful, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is late but the answer is very easy:
this happens When  using docker and you have SELinux,  be  aware that the host has no knowledge of container SELinux policy.
**by adding z**

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /wmi/tutorials/docker/src/:/var/www/html/:z hello-world
```

this will automatically do the `chcon ....` that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the **html** folder has the proper permission or not.
Thank you